# Gantt chart in Kibana

Tags: charts, kibana, gantt-chart

Any idea how to create **gantt chart** visualisation in **Kibana** with given data:

```
{
   "status" : "Setup",
   "timestamp" : "2017-07-04T00:00:00.000Z",
   "duration" : "5400"
},
{
   "status" : "Running",
   "timestamp" : "2017-07-04T01:30:00.000Z",
   "duration" : "11700"
},
...
```

Thank you for all replies.

Comment: Do you have any code showing how you're generating a Gantt chart based on the data?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: To be honest, I didn't even realise there's any coding involved in Kibana. I thought it's only about UI and clicks.